# How can my "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" wait until call api finish

Tags: ios, swift, api

How can my application wait until my call api is finished ?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzadGlsfR35k4BeHCXmRq3GDSQ-l_5gcD8")
    FlicAuth.sharedInstance

    //Call Api here

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    if(launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil){
        LocationService.sharedInstance.startMonitoringLocation()
    }

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: Can we ask why you would want to do that?

Comment: You don't want it to wait. If it takes too long, iOS will kill your app for taking to long to launch.

Comment: I want to change my first screen depending on the data i get from the api call

Comment: You need to show something immediately and return. Show some sort of "loading" screen and then do the API call in the background. Update the screen when you get the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very wrong, but for your problem i've a better solution.

Create a viewController exactly same as your splash screen and set as initial viewController.. perform your operation in that viewController's class and after Api success you can navigate to your actual screen or change the root programmatically

Comment: Thank's this is the best solution